# Hide Scrollbars In DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have selected 'None' for the ScrollBars property, but this prevents me from scrolling with the mousewheel. I would either like to remove scrollbars or hide them, while still allowing the mousewheel to scroll. Is this possible?

I solved it (Can't answer it for 8 hours...)

Subscribe to the MouseWheel event & in the function...

```
if(e.Delta > 0 && DGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingIndex > 0)
{
    DGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingIndex--;
}
else if(e.Delta < 0)
{
    DGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingIndex++;
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you add your solution as an answer and mark as accepted when the eight hour restriction is up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Subscribe to the MouseWheel event & in the function...

```
if(e.Delta > 0)
{

}
else if(e.Delta < 0)
{
}
```